# Percentage from TOTAL in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

there is any way to calculate the first 80% percentage

```
select
testoo.ttamount,
egct.Category_name,
SUM(pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)
    Line_amount,
ROUND ( SUM((pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)*100) / (testoo.ttamount) , 2 )  PERCENTAGE,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE


FROM


(SELECT 
SUM(test.line_amount) TTAmount

FROM
( select 
egct.Category_name,
SUM(pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)
    Line_amount,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE




 from EGP_CATEGORIES_TL  egct,
PO_LINES_ALL pola,
PO_HEADERS_ALL poh
where
egct.category_ID=pola.category_ID
AND pola.po_header_id = poh.po_header_id
AND LANGUAGE='US'
AND TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE='STANDARD'
AND poh.APPROVED_FLAG='Y'
 group by 
egct.Category_name,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE,
poh.RATE ) Test ) Testoo,
EGP_CATEGORIES_TL  egct,
PO_LINES_ALL pola,
PO_HEADERS_ALL poh

where
egct.category_ID=pola.category_ID
AND pola.po_header_id = poh.po_header_id
AND LANGUAGE='US'
AND TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE='STANDARD'
AND poh.APPROVED_FLAG='Y'



 group by 
egct.Category_name,
poh.RATE,
testoo.ttamount,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE


order by
Line_amount desc
```

for example the output
Category Percentage
1     32%
2     20%
3     20%
4     10%
5     18%

I want to get the high percentage which the percentage of it about 80 %
so the output will be

Category Percentage
1     32%
2     20%
3     20%
4     10%
5     18%

thanks.

Comment: Analytic function `RATIO_TO_REPORT`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/RATIO_TO_REPORT.html

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of percentage to get the first 80%

Comment: btw, you can also PERCENT_RANK: `select * from (select ..., PERCENT_RANK()over(your_value_for_calc) pr from t) where pr<=0.8`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to calculate each percentage:

```sql
with t(x) as (
  select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5))
)
select *
from (
  select 
    x, 
    ratio_to_report(x)over() rtr,
    percent_rank()over(order by x) pr
  from t
)
where pr<=0.8;
```

Results:

```sql
         X        RTR         PR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 .033333333          0
         1 .033333333          0
         2 .066666667 .222222222
         2 .066666667 .222222222
         3         .1 .444444444
         3         .1 .444444444
         4 .133333333 .666666667
         4 .133333333 .666666667

8 rows selected.
```

Another variant for cumulative percentage filter:

```sql
select *
from (
  select v.*, 100*sum(rtr)over(order by r) cumulative_percentage
  from (
       select 
          rownum r,
          column_value val,
          ratio_to_report(column_value) over() rtr 
       from table(sys.odcinumberlist(10,40,30,20))
       ) v
)
where cumulative_percentage<=80;

         R        VAL        RTR CUMULATIVE_PERCENTAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
         1         10         .1                    10
         2         40         .4                    50
         3         30         .3                    80

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: `percent_rank` has to do with returning 80% of *rows*, out of the total number of rows in the input. I don't think that has anything to do with the OP's problem; he wants to return rows (no matter how many, out of the total number of input rows) whose ***values*** in the "percentage" column add up to (approx.) 80%.